# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; error in line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to make a simple table in MySQL with this command;

```
CREATE TABLE users (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY,
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Then, I get this error;

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for  the right syntax to use near ', firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,  lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL, email varchar(' at line 1

Can you guys help me? I'm still new with Mysql...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `KEY` keyword

```
CREATE TABLE users (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned Primary Key wrongly.
Use code :-

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

);